How to optimize Vision Transformer (ViT) model training for medical image analysis?
I'm currently working on a research project involving the use of Vision Transformer (ViT) models for lung cancer detection from chest X-ray and CT scan images. While I have some experience with traditional CNNs, I'm relatively new to ViTs and am encountering several challenges. Here are some specifics:
Data Preprocessing: What are the best practices for preprocessing medical images for ViT models? Should I use any specific augmentations or normalization techniques?
Training Stability: I'm experiencing instability during training, such as fluctuating loss and accuracy. What are some recommended strategies to stabilize training for ViT models?
Hyperparameter Tuning: Are there any specific hyperparameters (e.g., learning rate, batch size) that I should focus on adjusting for optimal performance with ViTs?
Transfer Learning: Is transfer learning effective with ViT models in the medical imaging domain? If so, which pre-trained models or datasets would you recommend starting with?
Computational Resources: ViTs require a lot of computational power. Are there any techniques or tricks to reduce the computational load without significantly impacting performance?
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# Example data generator setup
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True
)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/train',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary'
)

# Example ViT model setup
vit_model = tf.keras.applications.VisionTransformer(
    input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
    include_top=True,
    weights=None,
    classes=2
)

vit_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = vit_model.fit(train_generator, epochs=10)

